# How to merge matrix based on row and column names

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to merge two matrices based on row and column names. Here is an example:

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(mat1) <- c("A", "B", "C")
rownames(mat1) <- c("x", "y", "z")
mat1

  A B C
x 0 0 1
y 0 1 0
z 1 1 0

mat2 <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol = 6)
colnames(mat2) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
rownames(mat2) <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
mat2

  A B C D E F
w 0 0 0 0 0 0
x 0 0 0 0 0 0
y 0 0 0 0 0 0
z 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I efficiently write the values of `mat1` into `mat2`? I would like to obtain:

```
  A B C D E F
w 0 0 0 0 0 0
x 0 0 1 0 0 0
y 0 1 0 0 0 0
z 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I have tried `for` loops but that seems tedious and inefficient. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 'mat2' is a super set of 'mat1', then use the row/column indexing to subset the 'mat2' and assign the 'mat1'

```
mat2[row.names(mat1), colnames(mat1)] <- mat1
mat2
#   A B C D E F
# w 0 0 0 0 0 0
# x 0 0 1 0 0 0
# y 0 1 0 0 0 0
# z 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: @SFront Thank you;.  Can I know your expectations

Comment: And how do you do it if it is not the super set? Is it `mat2[which(row.names(mat1) == row.names(mat2)), which(colnames(mat1) == colnames(mat2))] <- mat1[which(row.names(mat1) == row.names(mat2)), which(colnames(mat1) == colnames(mat2))]` ?

Comment: @SFront  I meant is `i1 <- match(row.names(mat2), row.names(mat1), nomatch = 0);i2 <- match(row.names(mat1), row.names(mat2), nomatch = 0);j1 <- match(colnames(mat2), colnames(mat1), nomatch = 0);j2 <- match(colnames(mat1), colnames(mat2), nomatch = 0);mat2[i2, j2] <- mat1[i1, j1]`

Comment: @SFront  I guess I answered the example you posted